# Is the literal object syntax only available for OS X development?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, xcode4, objective-c-literals

Are the new Objective-C literal syntax additions (e.g. `@3.14`) only available when developing for OS X and not iOS? That's what the Xcode update 4.4 seems to suggest. If so, why?

Comment: Exactly what I thought when I read the release notes too. Good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they’re also available in the 4.5 preview and work on iOS.

Comment: in the 4.4 final version which should be live on the app store now as well